# Looping in Q language

Tags: kdb

I am trying to figure out Q language basics. I am trying a sample program in which let's say for a given number I can find the sum of  all the multiples of 3 and 5?

if input is 10 sum : 23

I am trying to think in terms using of til and sum but cannot but to no avail till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q)sum where 0=min(til 10)mod/:3 5
23
```

In steps, we just apply our mod over 5 and 3 rather than doing them separately.

```
q)(til 10)mod 3
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
q)(til 10)mod 5
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
q)(til 10)mod/:3 5
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
q)
```

With this result we have 2 lists; ((til 10)mod 3;(til 10)mod 5). If we went to index 3 of each of these we would have (0;3). This means that our number is divisible by 3 but not 5. We only care whether it's divisible by either, so we can take the minimum.

```
q)min(til 10)mod/:3 5
0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 2 0
q)
```

Next we simply find the indexes where mod is zero;

```
q)where 0=min(til 10)mod/:3 5
0 3 5 6 9
q)
```

And since these indexes are of the same value as the actual values at those indices, we can just sum them. Giving;

```
q)sum where 0=min(til 10)mod/:3 5
23
q)
```

If it were the case that the indices and values at those indices were not equivalent then we would need to index into the original list and sum the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
q)sum where (or/) 0=(til 10) mod/: 3 5
23
```

Comment: Hello Ryan,

Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain your code also?

Comment: specifically I am not getting (or/) and /: 3 5 .